# codeigniter : inserting data/record into 2 tables with the same id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have two tables. the first table is **tb_mhs** and the second **user**.

how do you make the `id_user` in the `tb_mhs` table the same as the `id_user` in the user table?

thank you very much for your attention

---

[tb_mhs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzG1T.png)
[user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrkfy.png)

**Controller Code :-**

```
$email = $this->input->post('email');
$nama = $this->input->post('nama');
$password = SHA1($this->input->post('password'));
$data1 = array(
        'email'=>$email,
        'password'=>$password,
        'nama'=>$nama,
        'level'=>2,
        'status'=>0
);
$i=$this->input;
$npm = $this->register_m->create('user',$data1);
$data = array(

            'email' => $i->post('email'),
            'password' => SHA1 ($i->post('password')),
            'npm' => $i->post('npm'),
            'nama' => $i->post('nama'),
            'j_kelamin' => $i->post('j_kelamin'),
            'kelas_id' => $i->post('kelas_id'),
            'angkatan_id' => $i->post('angkatan_id'),
            'internal_id' => $i->post('internal_id'),
            'eksternal_id' => $i->post('eksternal_id'),
            'latitude' => -6.873776,  
            'longitude' => 107.575639,
            'berkas' => $i->post('berkas'),
            );
// $insert = $this->register_m->create('user',$data1);
$insert1 = $this->register_m->create('tb_mhs',$data);
$this->session->set_flashdata('sukses', 'Data Registrasi Berhasil di Tambahkan');
redirect(base_url('register/viewdataregistrasi'), 'refresh');
}
```

}

### Model

```
    public function create($table, $data)
{
    $query = $this->db->insert($table, $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: is there any relationships between 2 tables?

Comment: you want to insert `$data` in table `tb_mhs `

Comment: there is no related table between the tb_mahasiswa and user tables sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CI has Query Helper function call `$this->db->insert_id()`, it returns the insert ID number when performing database inserts.

After the line

```
$npm = $this->register_m->create('user',$data1);
```

Add this code

```
$newUserID = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Then update your **$data** array like this

```
$data = array[
            'id_user' => $newUserID,
            'email' => $i->post('email'),
            'password' => SHA1 ($i->post('password')),
            'npm' => $i->post('npm'),
            'nama' => $i->post('nama'),
            'j_kelamin' => $i->post('j_kelamin'),
            'kelas_id' => $i->post('kelas_id'),
            'angkatan_id' => $i->post('angkatan_id'),
            'internal_id' => $i->post('internal_id'),
            'eksternal_id' => $i->post('eksternal_id'),
            'latitude' => -6.873776,  
            'longitude' => 107.575639,
            'berkas' => $i->post('berkas'),
            ];
```

Rest of code is good.

For more information [Read](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html?highlight=insert_id).